# Convergence of $\sum \limits_{n=m}^{\infty}1/n^{3}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I want to find $A$ such that $$A\sum \limits_{n=m}^{\infty}1/n^{3}=1$$

for any natural value of $m$.

Comment: $A = \frac{1}{\sum_{k=m}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^3}}$ there you go :)

Comment: So $A$ is to be solved in terms of $m$?

Comment: It is just $\zeta(3)=1.202$ minus finitely many terms.

Comment: Yes @SimplyBeautifulArt

Comment: I know that for big values of $m$ the solution can be $A=2m^{2}$, but for minor values there's no solution that does not involve a many terms sum?

Comment: No, the solution can never be $A=2m^2$, since $2m^2$ is rational, whereas $A$ is irrational.

Comment: @DietrichBurde, sorry, I meant that this solution is an approximation

Comment: $\large -\,{2 \over \Psi''\left(m\right)}$. $\Psi$: Digamma Function.

Answer (score 3):

In terms of the [Hurwitz zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz_zeta_function):

$$A=\frac1{\zeta(3,m)}$$

There is no further closed form, unless you allow

$$A=\frac1{\zeta(3)-\sum_{n=1}^{m-1}\frac1{n^3}}$$

Approximations may be done with the Euler-Maclaurin formula:

$$\sum_{n=1}^m\frac1{n^3}\approx\zeta(3)+\frac1{2m^2}+\frac1{2m^3}+\dots$$

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know the Hurwtiz zeta function. But you meant ζ(3,m), right?

Comment: Yes, that was my bad.

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested in approximations,

$$A = 2m^2 - 2m + 1 - \frac{1}{6 m^2} - \frac{1}{6 m^3} + \frac{1}{12 m^4} + \frac{1}{3m^5} + O\left(\frac{1}{m^6}\right) \ \text{as}\ m \to \infty $$